# Groovyc successfully compiles invalid groovy scripts

Tags: groovy

```
c:\>cat invalid.groovy
com.test.build(binding)

c:\junk>groovyc invalid.groovy

c:\junk>ls invalid.class
invalid.class
```

Why does this not result in an compilation error? There is no such method com.test.build!

In what scenario will this compilation be successful?

Answer (score 0):

As Groovy is dynamic it cannot know that there will be no `com.test.build` at runtime

`com` may be an object added to the binding at a later date in the code's execution

---

An example:

Say we have this bit of groovy inside `Script.groovy`

```
com.test.build( binding )
```

Compile it with groovyc:

```
groovyc Script.groovy
```

Then, keep the `Script.class` file, and throw away the groovy script to make sure we are using the class file:

```
rm Script.groovy
```

Now, say we have the following in `Runner.groovy`

```
// Create a class which you can call test.build( a ) on
class Example {
  Map test = [
    build : { it ->
      println "build called with parameter $it"
    }
  ]
}

// Create one of our Com objects
def variable = new Example()

// Load the Script.class, and make an instance of it
def otherscript = new GroovyClassLoader().loadClass( 'Script' ).newInstance()

// Then, set `com` in the scripts binding to be our variable from above
otherscript.binding.com = variable

// Then, run the script
otherscript.run()
```

That prints:

```
build called with parameter groovy.lang.Binding@7bf35647
```

So as you can see, it gets the `test` parameter of the `com` object (the map above) and calls the `build` closure with the binding as a parameter...

Hope this makes sense...

Comment: Thanks so if i add "com.test.build" jar's then if i execute the said file i can able to run

Comment: Probably not, as I said, it's probably waiting for an object called `com`

Comment: Thanks I'm confused with this part "probably waiting for an object called com" can u explain a little, what's dynamic then

Comment: @anish Added an example... hope it makes sense -- tell me if not, and I'll try and think of another way to explain what I mean :-)

Comment: Thanks make sense, but if we add the required jar's file to this class then what will happen.

Comment: It won't work, as I believe Groovy will be looking for an object named `com`

Comment: @anish ie: not a package named `com`.  Just tried a quick test, and I couldn't get it to work if `com` was a package name added at runtime